# "Encode" integers from an array via a given scheme to characters

Tags: java, arrays

Since I'm rather new to Java, I am not familiar with all the ways of handling this type of an assignment. I studied C and C# throughout my high school but I just started Java few days ago.

The task goes like this:

Write a program that reads 10 single-digit integers and displays a string consisting
of 10 characters using the coding scheme:
Digit Corresponding Character
0-a
1-b
2-c
… …
9-j
For example, if input consists of the 10 digits 1 8 6 1 0 3 1 8 5 5, the application
responds with "bigbadbiff."

Since I moved from C and C# at first I had trouble allowing user to input the integers of the array, but I got that figured out. And this is what I got so far.

```
import java.util.*;

public class UnsualCoding
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner util = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] x = new int[5];
        int counter = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < x.length && util.hasNextInt(); i++)
        {
            x[i] = util.nextInt();
            counter++;
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n");
        System.out.println("Our array looks like");

        for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(x[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("\n\n");

    }

}
```

Should I create a list, copy the content from an array to it and do the change or should I approach this problem differently? Can I convert the array to string? Also how can I bind/assign the characters to the given numbers?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a school assignment?  If so, it should be tagged `homework`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are only 10 possibilities, you could put the characters that you want to encode into an array, and use the int inputs as the index to that array.

```
char[] y = new char[]{'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j'};
```

Then the only part of your code that would change would be where you print it out :

```
System.out.println(y[x[i]]);
```

Though you may want to change your x array to be of arbitrary length as well.

Comment: Thank you, this has solved my problem, easy yet brilliant idea. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int count = 10;
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(count);
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) result.append((char)(input.nextInt() + 'a'));
System.out.println(result);
```

**INPUT:**

```
1 8 6 1 0 3 1 8 5 5
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
bigbadbiff
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html?is-external=true) each numeric value to a letter.  Then you pull from the Map for each number found in the input string.  You will need a String to keep track of all the retrieved characters.  After that you can return the String that was created.

Comment: I will be looking into this more. Thanks a lot for the answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you need some kind of *mapping* between digits and characters representing them. When you need *mapping* best to have is a `Map`!

```
Map <Integer, Character> digitToCharacter = new HashMap<Integer, Character>();
char baseCharacter = 'a';
for (int i = 0; i< 10 ; i++) {
    digitToCharacter.put(i, baseCharacter++);
}

System.out.println("--" + digitToCharacter.get(1));
```

during your printing of content:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(x[i]);
    }
```

you would simply need to get value from map:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        System.out.println( digitToCharacter.get(i)));
    }
```

but because you need a `String`, you don't have to write values to output - you need to append them to single string.

```
    String result = null;
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++)
    {
        result += digitToCharacter.get(i)); // that isn't performace optimal, but it's enough and good for begginer
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I will certainly need this for my other assignment today.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create a list, copy the content from an array to it and do the change or should I approach this problem differently?

You could use a list to accumulate the result, or you could print the result as you accumulate it (you can use `System.out.print(ch)` to print an individual character).

> Also how can I bind/assign the characters to the given numbers?

You could declare:

```
char[] symbols = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'};
```

Then, `symbols[d]` is the `symbol` for digit `d`.

Or you might use that in unicode, lowercase letters occupy a contiguous range of character codes in alphabetical order, and use arithmetic to compute the codepoint of the next character: `char symbol = (char) ('a' + digit)`;

Comment: Thank you, I will use this as an alternate solution to the assignment.